# SharePoint 2010: Custom Silverlight Web Part history field

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint

I'm creating a custom application to view, create and manage a SharePoint 2010 list through a Silverlight 3 application. **NOTE**: It is a client side application

I've managed pretty much all the basic functions, loading the items of the list, creating new items, editing them etc... but I'm stuck with one specific function.

I have a text field ("multiple lines of text" in SharePoint) which has versioning activated, so as to keep a track of who, and when, each comment was made.

My problem is that I can't find a way to access the previous entries, using:

```
var comments = myListItem.FieldValues["Comments"];
commentsField.Text = comments.ToString();
```

returns a string of the most recent entry, but not of the previous entries.

I would like to be able to access all the comments made, together with who made them and when they were made.

Could you help me or point me to the right direction?

Thanks,
Kenny

Comment: Will get more focused answer if you post the code where you got stuck.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really have any code for this, I'm just trying to retrieve the values of this field and I get the object not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach (SPList list in yourList)
{
    foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
    {
        foreach (SPListItemVersion version in item.Versions)
        {
            SPField temp = version.Fields["Comments"];
            //use your temp 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Flowerking, thanks for you post. I'm using the Client Object Model and from what I understand I don't have access to the class "SPListItemVersion". There doesn't seem to be any equivalent in the set of classes I have using "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client". Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I couldn't find anything similar in client object model. However if you want to work from client side, you can also consider working with [version.asmx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/versions.versions_methods(v=office.12).aspx)